# JDBC batch with PreparedStatement not working in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

SPEC : MYSQL 5.7.16,JDK1.7,TOMCAT 8,mysql-connector-java-6.0.4.jar,WINDOWS 10

The Code below does not update batch method to db

```
Preparestatement pst = null;
String[] sqlx = {
"insert to abc('col1','col2')values('first', 'data')"
"insert to abc('col1','col2')values('second','data')"
"insert to abc('col1','col2')values('third', 'data')"
};

for(String sqIn : sqlx){
  pst = <jdbcConn>.preparestatement(sqIn);
  pst.addBatch();
}
int[] chkSql = pst.executeBatch();
//check if chkSql consists of 0..rollback else commit for > 0
```

On debug mode of the code, chkSql always has '1' ..this is dizzy ? 
Only 1 row is inserted successfully , others are not inserted.

Is this a bug with MYSQLDB or JAR  ????

Comment: I think you should `pst.executeBatch()` inside the `for`

Comment: your String array does not even compile. you are missing `,` after each string

Comment: Good checking of the executeBatch, although there is more you should check for: `if (chkSql[x] == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) throw Exception();` although it'll be implementation dependent. Still having issues with mysql myself so can't be definitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Statement stmt = null;
String[] sqlx = {
    "insert into abc(col1,col2) values('first', 'data')",
    "insert into abc(col1,col2) values('second','data')",
    "insert into abc(col1,col2) values('third', 'data')"
};
for(String sqIn : sqlx){
    stmt.addBatch(sqIn);
}
int[] chkSql = stmt.executeBatch();
```

try running this code. connection is your `Connection` object. also don't use a prepared statement if you don't want to set values at runtime.

Have a look for this kind of queries [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/),

and, prepared statements [here](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/)

I hope this helps you to understand when to use what

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are creating a new [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) at each iteration, so the `executeBatch()` will only be applied to the last `PreparedStatement` object.

Furthermore, `PreparedStatement` is used to avoid SQL injection and it takes care of values escaping, when you use the `?` placeholders system.

The [addBatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch()) method you are using is meant to work with variable parameters :

> **void addBatch()
>                 throws SQLException**
>
> Adds a set of parameters to this PreparedStatement object's batch of
>   commands.

, not with raw queries like you tried to do (for that, you would use [addBatch(java.lang.String query)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch(java.lang.String))

> **void addBatch(String sql)
>                 throws SQLException**
>
> Adds the given SQL command to the current list of commmands for this
>   Statement object. The commands in this list can be executed as a batch
>   by calling the method executeBatch.

The following example should do what you want :

```
String[][] data = { { "first", "data" }, { "second", "data" }, { "third", "data" } };

String sql = "insert into abc(col1,col2) values (?, ?)";// use placeholders

PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);// create a single statement

for (String[] row : data) {

       // set parameters
       pst.setString(1, row[0]);
       pst.setString(2, row[1]);

       pst.addBatch();// validate the set
}

int[] chkSql = pst.executeBatch(); // execute the batch of commands
//check if chkSql consists of 0..rollback else commit for > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea about JDBC/Java but your posted `INSERT` statement is plain wrong. You should never quote the column names else it will be considered as string literal rather a column. it should be

```
insert to abc(col1,col2)values('first', 'data')
```

As in your posted code, it should look like

```
String[] sqlx = {
"insert into abc(col1,col2)values('first', 'data')",
"insert into abc(col1,col2)values('second','data')",
"insert into abc(col1,col2)values('third', 'data')"
};
```

Comment: your sql does not work either. its insert into not insert to