# JDBC code not insering into Database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

The JDBC code is not throwing any exception but neither it is inserting or updating the database. Here is the code.
Also the database connectivity class is given after that. When I am executing it in my local with few data it is inserting fine into the DB. But while running it with like 1 million data, there is no DB operation getting reflected in DB. No exceptions are thrown by the code in either case.

```
 public static   void operateDocument(String result) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        OracleDataSource pds;

            pds = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();



        final int batchSize = 1000;
        int count = 0;

        JSONArray json;

        json = new JSONArray(result);

        Map<String, List<JSONObject>> orderMongo = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, List<JSONObject>> orderItemMongo = new HashMap<>();


        //  Document doc1=new Document();
        String key="";
        //Gson gson=new Gson();
        //BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
        List<JSONObject> nextlist = null;
        List<JSONObject> list=null;

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);

            if(obj.getString("table").equals("TEST.S_ORDER")){

                list = orderMongo.getOrDefault(obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ROW_ID"),new ArrayList<>());
                list.add(obj);
                orderMongo.put(obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ROW_ID"),list);
            }
            else if(obj.getString("table").equals("TEST.S_ORDER_ITEM")){
                nextlist = orderItemMongo.getOrDefault(obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ROW_ID"),new ArrayList<>());
                nextlist.add(obj);
                // System.out.println(obj);
                //  System.out.println(nextlist);
                key=obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ROW_ID");
                orderItemMongo.put(key, nextlist);

            }

        }

        Connection con=pds.getConnection("spring_kafka", "Aug2017");
        con.setAutoCommit(true);

        for (Entry<String, List<JSONObject>> entry : orderMongo.entrySet()) {
            List<JSONObject> listnext = entry.getValue();
            for(JSONObject obj:listnext){
                String op_type=obj.optString("op_type");
                switch(op_type){
                case "I":
                    pst=con.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
                    pst.setString(1,obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("STATUS_CD"));
                    pst.setString(2, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ROW_ID"));
                    pst.setString(3, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("INTEGRATION_ID"));
                    pst.setString(4, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_CUST_REF"));
                    pst.setString(5, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("REQ_SHIP_DT"));
                    pst.setString(6, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("QUOTE_ID"));
                    pst.setString(7, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ACCNT_ID"));
                    pst.setString(8, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ACTIVE_FLG"));
                    pst.setString(9, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("PROCESS_TIMESTAMP"));
                    pst.setString(10, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("CONTACT_ID"));
                    pst.setString(11, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("BU_ID"));
                    pst.setString(12, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("SHIP_CON_ID"));
                    pst.setString(13, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("LAST_UPD"));
                    pst.setString(14, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_CLOSE_DT"));
                    pst.setString(15, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_SUB_STAT"));
                    pst.setString(16, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ORDER_NUM"));
                    pst.setString(17, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("SOFT_DELETE"));
                    pst.setString(18, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("LAST_UPD_BY"));
                    pst.setString(19, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("REV_NUM"));
                    pst.setString(20, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ORDER_DT"));  
                    pst.addBatch();

                    break;
                case "U":
                    pst=con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
                    pst.setString(1,obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("STATUS_CD"));
                    pst.setString(2, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("INTEGRATION_ID"));
                    pst.setString(3, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_CUST_REF"));
                    pst.setString(4, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("REQ_SHIP_DT"));
                    pst.setString(5, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("QUOTE_ID"));
                    pst.setString(6, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ACCNT_ID"));
                    pst.setString(7, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ACTIVE_FLG"));
                    pst.setString(8, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("PROCESS_TIMESTAMP"));
                    pst.setString(9, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("CONTACT_ID"));
                    pst.setString(10, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("BU_ID"));
                    pst.setString(11, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("SHIP_CON_ID"));
                    pst.setString(12, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("LAST_UPD"));
                    pst.setString(13, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_CLOSE_DT"));
                    pst.setString(14, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_SUB_STAT"));
                    pst.setString(15, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ORDER_NUM"));
                    pst.setString(16, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("SOFT_DELETE"));
                    pst.setString(17, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("LAST_UPD_BY"));
                    pst.setString(18, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("REV_NUM"));
                    pst.setString(19, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ORDER_DT"));  
                    pst.setString(20, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ROW_ID"));
                    pst.addBatch();
                    break;
                case "D":
                    pst=con.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
                    pst.setString(1, obj.getJSONObject("after").optString("ROW_ID"));
                    pst.addBatch();
                    break;
                }

                if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
                    pst.executeBatch();
                }
                pst.executeBatch();
            //  con.commit();


                pst.close();        
            }

        }   
        //System.out.println(orderMongo);



    con.close();

        Connection secondcon=pds.getConnection("spring_kafka", "Aug2017");
        secondcon.setAutoCommit(true);
        System.out.println("Starting db op");
        for (Entry<String, List<JSONObject>> entry : orderItemMongo.entrySet()) {
            List<JSONObject> orderlist = entry.getValue();
            for(JSONObject object:orderlist){
            String op_type=object.optString("op_type");
            switch(op_type){
            case "I":
                prest=secondcon.prepareStatement(insertItemQuery);
                prest.setString(1, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ASSET_ID"));
                prest.setString(2, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("SERV_ACCNT_ID"));
                prest.setString(3, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("REQ_SHIP_DT"));
                prest.setString(4, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_PROD_DESC"));
                prest.setString(5, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("SHIP_CON_ID"));
                prest.setString(6, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_BES_STATUS"));
                prest.setString(7, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ROW_ID"));
                prest.setString(8, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("STATUS_CD"));
                prest.setString(9, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ORDER_ID"));
                prest.setString(10, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("COMPLETED_DT"));
                prest.setString(11, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("LAST_UPD"));
                prest.setString(12, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("SOFT_DELETE"));
                prest.setString(13, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("INTEGRATION_ID"));
                prest.setString(14, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_CDD"));
                prest.setString(15, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ACTION_CD"));
                prest.setString(16, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_ORDER_ITEM_SUBSTATUS"));
                prest.setString(17, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_APPT_REF"));
                prest.setString(18, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_CANCELLED_DT"));
                prest.setString(19, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("PROD_ID"));
                prest.setString(20, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("SERVICE_NUM"));
                prest.setString(21, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("MUST_DLVR_BY_DT"));
                prest.setString(22, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ROLLUP_FLG"));
                prest.setString(23, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ROOT_ORDER_ITEM_ID"));
                prest.setString(24, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("BILL_ACCNT_ID"));
                prest.setString(25, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("PROCESS_TIMESTAMP"));
                prest.setString(26, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("QTY_REQ"));
                prest.addBatch();
                break;
            case "U":
                prest=secondcon.prepareStatement(updateItemQuery);
                prest.setString(1, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ASSET_ID"));
                prest.setString(2, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("SERV_ACCNT_ID"));
                prest.setString(3, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("REQ_SHIP_DT"));
                prest.setString(4, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_PROD_DESC"));
                prest.setString(5, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("SHIP_CON_ID"));
                prest.setString(6, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_BES_STATUS"));
                prest.setString(7, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ORDER_ID"));
                prest.setString(8, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("STATUS_CD"));

                prest.setString(9,  object.getJSONObject("after").optString("COMPLETED_DT"));
                prest.setString(10, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("LAST_UPD"));
                prest.setString(11,object.getJSONObject("after").optString("SOFT_DELETE") );

                prest.setString(12, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("INTEGRATION_ID"));
                prest.setString(13,object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_CDD") );
                prest.setString(14,object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ACTION_CD") );
                prest.setString(15,object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_ORDER_ITEM_SUBSTATUS") );
                prest.setString(16,  object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_APPT_REF"));

                prest.setString(17,object.getJSONObject("after").optString("X_CANCELLED_DT"));
                prest.setString(18,object.getJSONObject("after").optString("PROD_ID") );

                prest.setString(19, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("SERVICE_NUM"));
                prest.setString(20,  object.getJSONObject("after").optString("MUST_DLVR_BY_DT"));
                prest.setString(21, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ROLLUP_FLG"));
                prest.setString(22, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ROOT_ORDER_ITEM_ID"));
                prest.setString(23, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("BILL_ACCNT_ID"));
                prest.setString(24,  object.getJSONObject("after").optString("PROCESS_TIMESTAMP"));
                prest.setString(25, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("QTY_REQ"));
                prest.setString(26, object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ROW_ID"));
                prest.addBatch();
                break;
            case "D":
                prest=secondcon.prepareStatement(deleteItemQuery);
                prest.setString(1,object.getJSONObject("after").optString("ROW_ID"));
                prest.addBatch();
                break;

            }
            if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
                prest.executeBatch();
            }
            prest.executeBatch();
            //secondcon.commit();
            prest.close();
        }






        }


        secondcon.close();

        System.out.println("Ending db op");


    }   
}
```

public static  OracleDataSource getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

```
    OracleDataSource oracleDS =null;
    oracleDS=new OracleDataSource();
    oracleDS.setDriverType("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    oracleDS.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl");
    oracleDS.setUser("spring_kafka");
    oracleDS.setPassword("Aug2017");

    /*oracleDS.setConnectionCachingEnabled(true);
    oracleDS.setConnectionCacheName("MYCACHE");
      Properties cacheProps = new Properties();
      cacheProps.setProperty("MinLimit", "1");
      cacheProps.setProperty("MaxLimit", "500");
      cacheProps.setProperty("InitialLimit", "1");
      cacheProps.setProperty("ConnectionWaitTimeout", "5");
      cacheProps.setProperty("ValidateConnection", "true");
      oracleDS.setConnectionCacheProperties(cacheProps);
      */

    /*Connection con=null;
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.50.84.85:1521:orcl","spring_kafka","Aug2017");*/
    return oracleDS;
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this to see what is happening inside the loop?

Comment: The value passed to `setDriverType` is incorrect, however because you set the URL the incorrect value is ignored. You should remove the call to `setDriverType`.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit : 
[JDBC batch with PreparedStatement not working in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996436/jdbc-batch-with-preparedstatement-not-working-in-mysql)

You also seem to be creating a new prepareStatement on each iteration, aren't you?

Comment: if I move the preparedStatement outside the switch case, then I would need six preparedStatements each for one op_type, handling which might be difficult. Is there any alternative like I don't need different PreparedStaments and can use two PreparedStatment variables to handle the operation.

Comment: You are creating multiple `PreparedStatements`. That's ok. You are calling `addBatch` on these multiple `PreparedStatements`. That's also ok. You are using only one variable to refer to these multiple `PreparedStatements`. That's a problem. Each pass through the loop creates a new `PreparedStatement` then calls `addBatch`. I don't see where `pst` is declared, but the next pass through the loop assigns a new value to it making the previous one unreachable. So very few of the `PreparedStatements` are executed since most of them are rendered unreachable before `executeBatch` is called.